How can I install pip on FreeBSD?
I was trying to install python and pip on my FreeBSD 15.0 server. It seems like I've successfully installed python. Now I have both Python3.9 and Python 3.11. However, I can't find and package called "pip" or "python-pip". I've also tried package name "python311-pip", "python3-pip" and "py311-pip".
How can I install pip?

I've solved this problem. I used "pkg install py311-pip" and it works.
